# Offline XNA Deployment to XBOX. Can it be done?

Tags: xna, xbox360, xna-4.0

Well,

The question is pretty explicit on its own. I want to know if I can deploy a game from my PC directly to a XBox. I'm not a professional developer of games, I do it on my free time because it amuses me, but nothing else. Im planning on buying an XBox but only if I can connect directly to my Visual Studio and test the games. I don't want to connect to XNA creators club or anything like it, is this possible?

I have XNA 4.0 with VS Ultimate 2k10

Best regards and many thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need to be connected to Xbox Live at all times. If the connection drops for any reason you will be kicked out of your game. Therefore, if you are offline, you cannot run any XNA games.

You also need an XNA Creators Club membership to deploy onto the Xbox 360. This plus Xbox Live Gold will set you back about $150. If you are a student you can get a free version of the XNA Creators Club membership over to www.dreamspark.com. However, it is not the same as the full version and does have limitations.

Comment: Like the tune says: Sad but true! thanks a lot for the insight, i think ill keep in the old school of directX

Answer (score 3):

Well, you do need the XNA Creators Club membership activated on your Xbox, in order to get their app running (which connects to your computer and to the Visual Studio add-in). But once you have that app in your Xbox, the act of running (or debugging) your game is as simple as hitting the "Start Debugging" button in VS. The game is automatically transferred to your Xbox and starts. You can even pause it and debug it via Visual Studio. It's really neat!